# How can I fill this cardioid blue?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I fill this polar cardioid blue?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->,>=latex] (-2,0)--(2.5,0) node[above] {$x$};
\draw[thick,->,>=latex] (0,-2)--(0,2) node[left] {$y$};
\draw[domain=0:540,scale=1.5,samples=500] plot (\x:{cos(\x/3)^3});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: add `fill=blue` to the option.

Comment: No. Not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: cardioid in blue]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[smooth,cyan,fill=blue] plot[domain=0:540,samples=200] (\x:{cos(\x/3)^3});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT: EVEN ODD RULE

Like hpekristiansen said in the comments, you can avoid to fill the small intersected area by using the `even odd rule`:

```
\draw[even odd rule,smooth,cyan,fill=blue] plot[domain=0:540,samples=200] (\x:{cos(\x/3)^3});
```

[image: Cardioid with even odd rule]

Comment: If preferred, fill of small area can be avoided with an `even odd rule` option

Comment: You're right, I didn't know if OP wanted it like this or like that. I'll edit my post.