# Geometry diagram in latex

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I want to make this diagram using latex.
Can anyone, please tell me how to do it?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!! This post could be a start pint: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604636/how-can-i-fill-this-cardioid-blue

Answer (score 2):

- first you need to solve *math* problem: write cardioid formula ...
- knowing it, drawing your diagram is simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = Straight Barb]
% axis
\draw[->]   (-0.5,0) node[left] {$x'$}
                     -- (2.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->]   (0,-1.2) node[left] {$y'$}
                     -- (0,1.5) node[right] {$y$};
\coordinate[pin=300:0] (aux);
% cardioid
\draw[semithick] plot[domain=0:540,samples=200] (\x:{1+cos(\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]